# Python mypy why does class instance attribute require type hint if expression already has type hint

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, static-typing

I have run into this case a few times:

1. An argument `arg` in a class's `__init__` has a type hint to be a `TypeVar`
2. An instance attribute `self.attr` is assigned to be `arg`
3. mypy raises errors if I don't specify a second type hint on `self.attr`

My question is, why do I need to specify the second type hint?

---

**Sample Code**

```py
from typing import AnyStr, Generic


class A(Generic[AnyStr]):
    def __init__(self, arg: AnyStr):
        # Case A... error: Need type annotation for 'attr'
        self.attr = arg

        reveal_type(arg)
        # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.str*'
        # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.bytes*'

        reveal_type(self.attr)
        # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
        # note: Revealed type is 'Any'


class B(Generic[AnyStr]):
    def __init__(self, arg: AnyStr):
        # Case B... Success
        self.attr = arg  # type: AnyStr
```

For `Case A`, I would think the type hint on `arg` should be propagated to `self.attr`, but it isn't.  Why is that?

---

Versions:

```
python==3.6.5
mypy==0.770
```

Comment: Because the best mypy can infer is `Any` unless you tell it otherwise, because *it is ambiguous*. Now, there is nothing to prevent special casing `__init__` here, but "explicit is better than implicit" and "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess." I see very little to be gained from not having to explicitly annotate the attributes

Comment: Yes I agree that being explicit is better, in general.  In the above example, the expression (`arg`) assigned to `attr` *is* explicitly typed as `AnyStr`.  mypy doesn't require type definitions on every single assignment, why should it require one in this case?

Comment: I think this might actually be a mypy bug. The way mypy handles typevars with multiple bounds is sort of janky (it first type checks your constructor assuming AnyStr is a str and again assuming it's a bytes), and this "replace and type check twice" could perhaps be confusing how mypy infers what type the attribute is. I'd try asking whether this really is a bug on the mypy issue tracker. (I'm a little surprised I wasn't able to find an existing issue for this, actually.)

Comment: Yes @Michael0x2a, it seems that the `builtins.str` aspect propagates, but it loses track of `builtins.bytes`.  When you refer to the "mypy issue tracker", do you just mean making an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Opened this: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8763